# how do i write a list to file in python

Tags: python, sqlite

i am a student learning python, for my project i am developing a stock management system using an SQLite.

I am a little stuck on saving the ' stock that needs to be ordered' to a text file. 
I guess i just need to save a list to a .txt file however ive been playing around for a few hours trying to figure out.

the SQL statment takes the data from the database, this data is what i want to save to a txt file.

i tried to use pickle.dump however it didnt work too well with the ("\n") as i wont it on a new line for every piece of data.

any help would be lovely...

my code is as follows:

```
import sqlite3, menus, pickle
def main():
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        data = int(input("Please enter the max number in stock you wish to disply: "))
        sql = "select * from Stock where NumberInStock between 0 and '{0}'".format(data)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        print(data[0])
        print()
        print(data[1])
        print()


    print('1. Save order list to a file')
    print('2. Do another order list')
    print('9. Quit')
    choice=int(input('what would you like to do?'))
    if choice ==1:

        pickle.dump(data("\n"), open('orderlist.txt','wb'))
        print('Your list has been saved...')

    elif choice ==2:
        main()
    elif choice ==9:
        menus.menu1()  
main()
```

Comment: `fetchall` returns a list.  What makes you think Python lists are callable?

Comment: as an aside, its not a good idea to have main() call main(). Put it all in a `while True:` block instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to answer one important question: "what format of data in my text file do I want?". Note that sqlite has its own data format and from that point of view you alread have your data in a file ( `mrsimms.db` ). This makes more sense especially since you are playing with `pickle` which is not really human readable.

Once you answer that it should be quite straight forward.

For example if you want to save it in CSV format, then this will do:

```
import csv
with open("orderlist.txt", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

If you want pickle:

```
with open("orderlist.txt", "wb") as f:
     pickle.dump(data, f)
```

`data("\n")` doesn't make much sense. `data` is a list since it is a result of `fetchall()`. Lists are not callable in Python.

If you want a pickle per line, then you can do this:

```
with open("orderlist.txt", "wb") as f:
    for row in data:
        pickle.dumps(row, f)
        f.write(b"\n")
```

although it is quite ugly. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a list to a  file using this method.

```
lines = ["line one \n", "line two \n", "line three \n"]
OutFile = open("lines.txt", "w")
OutFile.writelines(lines)
OutFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

@freakish has a great answer. If you want something human readable, you can write formatted strings to the file using the data you get from the select call. Assuming your database has a column called ProductName, you could could limit the result to the data you want to show (and remove a few lines of code by iterating the cursor) and do:

```
import sqlite3
def main():
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db") as db:
        with open('stock.txt', 'w') as fp:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            data = int(input("Please enter the max number in stock you wish to disply: "))
            sql = "select NumberInStock, ProductName from Stock where NumberInStock between 0 and '{0}'".format(data)
            for row in cursor.execute(sql):
                print(row) # should be something like (42, "Pickles")
                fp.write('We only have {0} {1}\n'.format(*row))
main()
```